# What's the upgrade path for Embedded Media Field from Drupal 6 to 7?

Tags: 7, entities, media, upgrading

I swear I've tried everything, and this is the very last piece that's keeping me from launching my upgraded site -- most of my nodes have video and/or audio in emfields.

The straight Content Migrate route kept on throwing errors every time it encountered and aborting the import. I edited the module to send the error messages to watchdog instead of the screen, but it still doesn't work -- it creates the tables in the DB but they're empty.

Someone out there must have achieved this ... any clues would be MUCH appreciated, I'm at my wits' end.

I've got the following installed:

Embedded Media Field 7.x-1.x-dev
Content Migrate 7.x-2.x-dev
Media + File Entity + Media Field + Media Internet Sources 7.x-2.0unstable6
7.x versions of all my Media: providers

I tried with the stable versions of all of these and switched to dev when those didn't work.